# Dynamic class definitions using Metaclass

Tags: python, metaclass

I am trying to create class definitions dynamically as follows.

```py
class SomeMetaclass(type):
  def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, clsdict):
    print("Using this metaclass")
    return super().__new__(cls, clsname, bases, clsdict)

SomeClassFoo = SomeMetaclass('SomeClassFoo', (), {})

# Similar to the following
# SomeClassFoo = type('SomeClassFoo', (), {})
```

However, I think I am missing something here. While the above example doesn't do what I would expect it to, the following method works:

```py
class SomeClassBar(metaclass=SomeMetaclass):
  pass
```

However, when I run `type(SomeClassFoo)` in both the examples, I get class `SomeMetaclass`?

```py
# The following statement is true
type(SomeClassFoo) is type(SomeClassBar)
```

Are the **prepare**/**new** methods not called when the class is defined using the former method?

Comment: "While the above example doesn't do what I would expect it to" - What do you expect it to do? What does it do instead?

Comment: Well, I was hoping it was clear.

"While the above example doesn't do what I would expect it to"

What I was hoping for was:

The **__new__**, **__prepare__** etc methods to be called? As I ask at the bottom?

*"Are the prepare/new methods not called when the class is defined using the former method?"*

Comment: I see `Using this metaclass` with the first example, if you aren't. I don't know what else you expect it to do that it's not doing.

Comment: No `__prepare__` method is called in either case, because you haven't defined one.

Comment: `__new__` *is* called; it's not clear why you think it is not.

Comment: @chepner hmm..its strange, I think I realise why this is causing confusion. I tried running this in a python shell and also in PDB debugger....It works as I would expect in the shell, however not in the PDB debugger

Comment: Can you show *exactly* how you are running this? I see `Using this metaclass` with `python3 -mpdb tmp.py` (and using the `c` command to continue the program after the initial break).

Comment: Maybe what is causing so much discussion is just that the snippets in the question did not include  a `__prepare__`  method. The question would make complete sense if there were a "printing `__prepare__`  " just as there is a "printing `__new__`". I ǘe answered with that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

All is working as expected. The question is currently regarded as low quality, as you likely forgot to put `__prepare__` implementation on your snippets, but from the comments, I imagine you are doing something like this:

```
class SomeMetaclass(type):

    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(mcls, name, bases):
        print(f"running __prepare__ for {name}")
        return super().__prepare__(name, bases)
        
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, clsdict):
        print(f"running  __new__  for {name}")
        return super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, clsdict)

SomeClass1 = SomeMetaclass('SomeClass1', (), {})

class SomeClass2(metaclass=SomeMetaclass):
    pass
```

Upon running it, the output is:

```
running  __new__  for SomeClass1
running __prepare__ for SomeClass2
running  __new__  for SomeClass2
```

As is visible here,  "SomeClass1" creation does not call `__prepare__`, rightly: the class namespace is already passed into the call as the third parameter which is `{}`,  and there is no body to be run.

When one wants to use metaclasses in a programatic way like this, including allowing Python to use the internal lookup mechanisms to get the correct `__prepare__` method, and use it manually, there are helpers in the [`types` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#dynamic-type-creation) that provide the means for that. There are two ways, one is calling
`types.prepare_class` which will find out the correct metaclass to call (if besides your explicit "metaclass" parameter, your "bases" include classes which also have metaclasses, the one to call is the most derived metaclass), run its `__prepare__` method, and return you the metaclass, the namespace created by `__prepare__`  and any remainder keyword arguments to call the metaclass. You can then call the returned metaclass as you see fit:

```
In [32]: metaclass, classdict, kwds  = types.prepare_class("SomeClass3", (), {"metaclass": SomeMetaclass})
running __prepare__ for SomeClass3

In [33]: metaclass("SomeClass3", (), classdict, **kwds)
running  __new__  for SomeClass3
Out[33]: __main__.SomeClass3
```

(note that between both calls you are supposed to populate "classdict" if you want something in there).

The other way is to call `types.new_class`: it does almost the samething, but instead of returning the class creation information for you, it will call the `metaclass.__new__` method directly. If you want to insert anything into the new class namespace, you have to pass it a 4th parameter, with a callback that will take the namespace as a parameter, it has to populate it, and return it:

```
In [34]: SomeClass3 = types.new_class("SomeClass3", (),  {"metaclass": SomeMetaclass})
running __prepare__ for SomeClass3
running  __new__  for SomeClass3

In [35]: def fill_classdict(classdict):
    ...:     classdict["attribute"] = 23
    ...: 

In [36]: SomeClass4 = types.new_class("SomeClass4", (),  {"metaclass": SomeMetaclass}, fill_classdict)
running __prepare__ for SomeClass4
running  __new__  for SomeClass4

In [37]: SomeClass4.attribute
Out[37]: 23
```